# Bokeh serve with SSL (HTTPS): Option ssl-certfile not recognized

Tags: ssl, bokeh

I want to serve bokeh charts using the building server option.
As specified in the doc, one can use the option --ssl-certfile /path/to/pem/cert in order to serve it as an SSL termination point.

> A Bokeh server can also terminate SSL connections directly by specifying the path to a single file in PEM format containing the certificate as well as any number of CA certificates needed to establish the certificate’s authenticity:
>   bokeh serve --ssl-certfile /path/to/cert.pem

However, if I try this

```
bokeh serve --ssl-certfile /Users/me/cert.pem
```

, I get:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: --ssl-certfile
```

I use the latest bokeh version 1.3.4

Any idea of what is happening???

Thanks,
Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not released yet. It will be in the next release version 1.4.

Edit: the way docs are hosted has recently changed completely, it looks like this information was accidentally published prematurely.